# How does gnome extensions website work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gnome

How does http://extensions.gnome.org work? The page shows all extensions on my pc, and you can install them online with a click. How does this website can access to operating system and make changes on my shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It communicates with a custom "GNOME Shell Integration" browser plugin. See https://extensions.gnome.org/static/js/dbus.js for the guts.

Note that it probably won't work outside the GNOME site, for obvious security reasons.